# Tax deduction for 529 for elementary school tuition

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, 529-plan

Well I had another question in mind, but my state NC has finally updated the 529 plans to include Elementary and High School.  So no my question is, I think I would prefer to use Vanguard or TRowe to do my 529 and not NC, would I lose any tax benefit or be punished in NC for not using theirs?

If no punishment, what is the advantage of using your state's 529s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deciding between my state 529 plan and either another states 529 plan or a plan not run by a state, the first question to ask is does my state allow a tax deduction for my contributions? And if so, does it only apply to contributions to the plan run by my state.

It appears that North Carolina doesn't give a tax break on contributions. The page describing the [tax benefits](http://nc529.org/the-tax-benefits/) doesn't mention a tax deduction on contributions.

Earnings on your NC 529 Account are free from North Carolina and federal taxes

> An important advantage of saving in an NC 529 Account is that earnings
>   on your account aren’t subject to North Carolina or federal taxes as
>   long as they, along with your contributions, are used to help pay for
>   Qualified Higher Education Expenses (QHEE). Tuition, fees, room and
>   board, books, computers and required equipment are examples of
>   expenses considered qualified.
>
> The earnings portion of withdrawals not used for QHEE expenses is
>   subject to federal income tax and a 10% federal penalty tax, as well
>   as state and local income taxes. The availability of tax benefits may
>   be contingent on meeting other requirements.
>
> The features of a qualified tuition program are complex and involve
>   significant tax issues. For more detail, visit the CFNC.org page here.

This means that putting 529 money into a program not run by your state would not cause you to miss a deduction for contributions.

The question now is will you be able to pull the money from a program not run by North Carolina and send it to your school. The tax law change is so new not all states/programs schools have made the necessary changes. If the plan you contribute to doesn't have a mechanism for sending money to the private K-12 school, you could have money locked in an account  that doesn't have a way to fund the education you want.